# How to pass map values on client side from component to controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, map, parameters, function

I currently have a child component to which I pass some map values from a parent component to an attribute in the child component on the client side. I used an example which gets map values from serverside.

I am getting the mapvalues from client side but want to remove the serversidepart from the controller

I currently have the following

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="mapValues" type="object" /> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getMapValues}"/>
```

Controller

```
    getMapValues : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getMap");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
                var result = component.get("v.mapValues");
                var arrayMapKeys = [];
                for(var key in result){
                    arrayMapKeys.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
                }
                component.set("v.mapValues", arrayMapKeys);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

I am expecting to be able to do the following:

```
getMapValues : function(component, event, helper) {
       
                var result = component.get("v.mapValues");
                var arrayMapKeys = [];
                for(var key in result){
                    arrayMapKeys.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
                }
                component.set("v.mapValues", arrayMapKeys);
    }
```

This throws me the error:

> Action failed: aura:iteration$controller$itemsChange [Maximum call
> stack size exceeded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack depth exceeded indicates an infinite recursive call. This might happen because the attribute is passed back and forth between parent and child infinitely for some reason. You may need a second attribute to fix this. I think you also need to use a change handler, instead:

```
<aura:attribute name="mapValues" type="Object" /> 
<aura:attribute name="localMapValues" type="Object" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.mapValues}" action="{!c.updateMapValues}"/>
```

---

```
updateMapValues: function(component, event, helper) {
  let mapValues = component.get("v.mapValues");
  let result = Object.keys(mapValues).map(function(key) {
    return ({ key, value: mapValues[key] });
  });
  component.set("v.localMapValues", result);
}
```

You'll need to update the remaining mappings in your child component to use the localMapValues attribute.